# What adventures are good for use with a square grid map?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, gm-preparation

I'm new as a DM, and I'm planning to run *Dragon of Icespire Peak* for a group of four players. However, I already can tell that it will be time-consuming to map out each of the potential locations the players might go to. I'm also worried that I might not have enough space to map each of the potential locations with my 3 double-sided 22x34 erasable maps. After I run DoIP, I'd like to DM another campaign. I'm considering several options, and I'd like to know how well each of the options conforms to the following standards (where higher-importance items are higher on the list):

- Fewer branches: I don't want to have to deal with running out of map space when mapping out each area in advance.
- Nice, square lines: areas with clean corners are much easier to map on a square grid.

The adventures I'm considering are:

- Waterdeep: Dragon Heist, followed by Dungeon of the Mad Mage
- Princes of the Apocalypse
- Tomb of Annihilation
- Candlekeep Mysteries

Comment: Just to be clear: you're looking to pre-draw maps for all the places your players are likely to go in a *session*, or for the whole campaign? I guess I'm not clear on your work-flow.